# Refresh access token for Service Principal authentication using 'ms-rest-nodeauth'

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, sequelize.js, service-principal

I have an application that needs to connect to Azure SQL Server and is using Sequelize as the ORM. I am trying to make the solution more secure by authenticating using a service principal. I am using the module @azure/ms-rest-nodeauth to obtain an access token and passing that to Sequelize in my DB initializer.
The function 'loginWithServicePrincipalSecret' gets me the access token by passing the SPN credentials.

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
      database: AZURE_SQL_DB,
      host: AZURE_SQL_SERVER,
      dialect: 'mssql',
      logging: true,
      dialectOptions: {
        authentication: {
          type: 'azure-active-directory-access-token',
          options: {
            token: accessToken,
          },
        }
      }
    })
```

Problem is that, though this works to make the connection, the access tokens expire after 1 hour. This would break the solution as it keeps listening for new requests and the token would be expired.

Is there a way to 'refresh' the token or maybe some elegant way to handle acquiring a new token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting what I ended up using for my solution.

Tedious supports authentication type 'azure-active-directory-service-principal-secret' which in the background uses @azure/ms-rest-nodeauth methods and handles the authentication.

```
{
  database: AZURE_SQL_DB,
  host: AZURE_SQL_SERVER,
  dialect: 'mssql',
  logging: true,
  dialectOptions: {
    authentication: {
      type: 'azure-active-directory-service-principal-secret',
      options: {
        clientId: AZURE_CLIENT_ID,
        tenantId: AZURE_TENANT_ID,
        clientSecret: AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try using the [Silent flow](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-node-samples/standalone-samples/silent-flow) with [MSAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js), which internally uses the refresh token to fetch new tokens as and when needed? [`acquireTokenSilent`](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/7cd420254b57b3a988446dc5774659a81a2bbd2a/lib/msal-browser/docs/token-lifetimes.md#token-renewal)(@azure/msal-node) can perform silent renewal of tokens, which means you are no need to get the refresh token by yourself.

```
var request = {
    scopes: ["Mail.Read"]
};

msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(request).then(tokenResponse => {
    // Do something with the tokenResponse
}).catch(error => {
    if (error instanceof InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
        // fallback to interaction when silent call fails
        return myMSALObj.acquireTokenRedirect(request)
    }
});
```

Comment: But would this let me authenticate using a service principal client id and secret?

Comment: Nope, it needs a signed-in user. If you still want to get the new token with client id and secret, you could only get the token again after the token expired. Because [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token) does not support [refresh-token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows#how-each-flow-emits-tokens-and-codes).