# azure-active-directory-service-principal-secret node sequelize migrations

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, azure-service-principal, dbconnection

I'm connecting db with service principal by using below method in express using
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66337370/refresh-access-token-for-service-principal-authentication-using-ms-rest-nodeaut)

but while running migrations it will establish connection from db.config file
where db.config file contains

```
  "development": {
"username": process.env.DB_USER,
"password": process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
"database": process.env.DB_DATABASE,
"host": process.env.DB_HOST,
"dialect": "mssql",
"logging": false
```

},

so how to configure the db.config file for service principal method

Answer (score 0):

> how to configure the db.config file for service principal method

Follow the below steps to configure the `db.config` file for service principal method:

- Create an `App registration` as shown below
  [image]
- Provide name of the application and click on `Register`:
  [image]
- Note the `ClientId` and `TenantId` after registering
  [image]
- Generate the client secret which is present in `Certificates & Secrets` and note the `secretId`.
  [image]
- Grant permissions to the Service Principal which you have created. To grant permission, navigate to the `Access control` which is present in the Azure server and go to `Add role assignment` as shown below.
  [image]
- Select role which is needed to access the db. I selected `SQL DB Contributor` role.
  [image]
- After selecting the role, select the member to which you want to assign the role.
  [image]

After adding the role assignment, now provide the required config details accordingly in the `db.config`

```js
module.exports = {
    development: {
      username: 'admin1',
      password: '*****',
      database: 'db1',
      host: 'server6391.database.windows.net',
      dialect: 'mssql',
      logging: false, // Set to true for Sequelize query logging
  
      authentication: {
        type: 'azure-active-directory-msi-app-service',
        options: {
          resource: 'https://database.windows.net/',
          tenantId: '******',
          clientId: '******'
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

By running your node application it will connect successfully to the db as you can see in the output below.
[image]